# How do you import dbase file into Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to import dbase III files into an Access 2016 database.  I actually had this working by installing Microsoft Jet Drivers for 2016 redistributable.  Then it stopped working. The message I get says 'You cannot use ODBC to import from, export to, or link an external Microsoft Access or ISAM database table to your database'.

Comment: I found a work around.  I used Access 2010 to open the database and import the dbase files.  I don't like this solution, but I am under a time crunch.

Answer (score 0):

In Access 2013, Microsoft removed support for interacting with dBase. In Office 365 and Office 2019 they have reintroduced it.

Check this reference:
[What's new in Access 2019.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-s-new-in-access-2019-f52c5317-3494-4105-9c56-5a2abb8e0f87)